# Which Facebook Privacy settings can be accessed through API?

Tags: facebook, api, privacy

I'm about to start an ASP.NET project which uses Facebook API to get/set Facebook Privacy settings.

Through some research I found out that changing these settings are not possible. 
Now I'm wondering which of these settings I can access at least to display the user his privacy options.
Can I only access the settings mentioned in this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/

or is there any other way to access other privacy settings, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can check the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/ table for the specific default setting they have for your app.

Comment: Thanks but I'm developing this application to keep the user aware of his/her own privacy settings, I doubt that they would care about the setting for my app.

Comment: For public safety that's all your 3rd party app is privy too.